# When does Satterthwaite-Welch's degree of freedom approximation break down?

Tags: t-test, degrees-of-freedom, satterthwaite

Are there conditions when the usual formula to approximating the degrees of freedom in a Satterthwaite method breaks down? I realized I've never asked myself this anyway, and I was exploring simulations to see how effective the DF approximation is. For instance, in this case, I generate sample 1 according to $X_1, \ldots, X_{10} \sim_{iid}\mathcal{N}(0, 3)$ then for sample 1, I consider n stepping down from 10 to 2 $Y_1, \ldots, Y_m \sim_{iid}\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

I generate the test statistic over a million simulations each, and then take the average Satterthwaite degree of freedom. By my eye, the density fit is not perfect, but I doubt I can crank up the simulations to get a reasonable answer within 3 days... so I wonder to ask here if others have researched the problem.
[image]